# How do I split the data on the basis of special character in sql server or databricks

Tags: sql-server, split

I have a data which contains column M_ID ,CustomerID, Dimensions

so I want split data into column on basis of special character (___) for column name - Dimension
It will be like this before special character should be goes to separate column that is column Name: key value and later part should be goes to Column name :Details

**Source data sample:**

| M_ID | CustomerID | Dimensions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 20000 | 2___17971690,8___THANE,20___Experia_app_bflcust,63___GTM-MJZ5DX7 - 234 - |

**Table structure should like this:**

| M_ID | CustomerID | Keyvalue | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 20000 | 2 | 17971690 |
| 12 | 20000 | 8 | THANE |
| 12 | 20000 | 20 | Experia_app_bflcust |

Comment: add your table structure here.  @siddhesh

Comment: updated the question with table structure Thanks @zambee

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: ok @Stu expected output: M_ID CustomerID Keyvalue Details
12 20000 2 17971690
12 20000 8 THANE
12 20000 20 Experia_app_bflcust

Comment: No do that in your question, not as a comment

Comment: @Charlieface Done in my question as well .Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You've just gone and posted another image. Please **avoid** the use of images, we need text to copy and paste, preferably `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements

Comment: Ok @Charlieface sir !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split up the data by `,`. Then use `CHARINDEX` to find the `___` and `SUBSTRING` to split out the two halves.

```sql
SELECT
  t.M_ID,
  t.CustomerID,
  SUBSTRING(s.Value, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('___', s.Value), 0) - 1) Keyvalue,
  SUBSTRING(s.Value, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('___', s.Value), 0) + LEN('___') + 1, LEN(s.Value)) Details
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Dimensions, ',') s;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f425c8d9360e6ca6f24e9dd3fe344407)

**Result**

| M_ID | CustomerID | Keyvalue | Details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 20000 | 2 | 7971690 |
| 12 | 20000 | 8 | HANE |
| 12 | 20000 | 20 | xperia_app_bflcust |
| 12 | 20000 | 63 | TM-MJZ5DX7 - 234 - |

Comment: query not working

Comment: could you please help me on this ?

Comment: Should work now

Comment: i tried from my end ,but its showing me error as Incorrect syntax near '('. Could you please suggest ?

Comment: i am using ssms version 17.4

Comment: SSMS version not relevant. Which version of SQL Server are you using `select @@version`? Can you construct a https://dbfiddle.uk of your current non-working query? Because it works in the fiddle linked above

Comment: ohh its showing me Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.13665.0

Comment: OK I rewrote it to use `SELECT` instead of `(VALUES` I think it might work now. I don't have access to Azure DW so can't test it, but judging from the docs it looks like the syntax should work

Comment: its showing me error near select (Parse error at line: 11, column: 13: Incorrect syntax near 'select'.)

Comment: yes i have run query using Cross apply

Comment: Please construct a fiddle showing failing syntax and point out which line is failing

Comment: there is no option available in fiddle , its my bad ..is there any option where i can show you .Could you please suggest ?

Comment: Not sure. I have had another go at rewriting it with simpler syntax, maybe try again